# django on apache 403 error

Tags: python, django, apache

I am getting "403 forbidden" when trying to access my website. I am using apache 2.4.1, django 1.8 and python 2.7. I tried to change

> Require all granted

in Files section to

> Order deny,allow Allow from all

But it doesn't work.

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        Alias /static /home/roma0851/project/meetingsSystem/static
        <Directory /home/roma0851/project/meetingsSystem/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>
        <Directory /home/roma0851/project/meetingsSystem/meetingsSystem>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
         WSGIDaemonProcess project python-path=/home/roma0851/project:/home/roma0851/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages
         WSGIProcessGroup meetingsSystem
         WSGIScriptAlias / /home/roma0851/project/meetingsSytem/meetingsSystem/wsgi.py

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Error log:

> [Wed Dec 02 11:32:15.699551 2015] [authz_core:error] [pid 11572:tid
>   140381727454976] [client 78.56.172.255:61955] AH01630: client denied
>   by server configuration: /home/roma0851/project/meetingsSytem

Comment: I doubt the Apache user has rights to access /home/roma0851.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 4 roma0851 root 4096 Oct 13 13:37 roma0851 . I think eveything is okay here with rights

Comment: If you remove Django, can Apache access files in that directory?

Comment: Now is okay with accessing directory, but now I have this error: `... wsgi.py cannot be loaded as Python module.`